# Is it possible to use fitVids or fluidVids with the YouTube iFrame API?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I've been able to render the video with no problems, except that I've not yet found it possible to use the player with fitVids or fluidVids. I'm assuming that this is because the Iframe is generated by JavaScript and not available to the resizing script. Is there a possible work around?

```
var youTubeApi = {

    player: '',

    init: function(){
        // Let's get the API script
        $.getScript('//www.youtube.com/iframe_api');
        // The API will ask for the player
        youTubeApi.createPlayer();
    },
    createPlayer: function(){

        onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
            youTubeApi.player = new YT.Player('player',{
                videoId: 'sF4fn82tWmQ',
                playerVars:{
                    autoplay: 1,
                    autohide: 1
                }
            })
        }
    }

}
youTubeApi.init();
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are initialising FluidVids after you've loaded your Youtube iframe.

```
fluidvids.init();
```